# Is calling aio_return necessary after aio_cancel?

Tags: aio

As I understand it calling `aio_return` is necessary to finalize `aio_read` and `aio_write` calls. So the normal flow is something like

1. Call `aio_read`
2. Determine that the read has completed (with `aio_error`, `aio_suspend` or receiving a signal via `aio_sigevent`
3. Call `aio_return` to finalize the read.

(steps 2 and 3 can be done with the `aio_waitcomplete` extension)

Is it necessary to call `aio_return` if the io is cancelled with `aio_cancel`, or does the cancel also finalise the io?

Also, does this depend on the implementation?

Comment: Perhaps some context would be useful here. This seems to refer to the FreeBSD `aio` OS facility.

Comment: I'm mainly looking at FreeBSD but I'd also like to know for macOS Linux and Illumos.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify.